# Passing additional parameters to event Action;

Tags: c#, .net, events, action

Definittion of `ProgressChanged`:

```
// Summary:
// Event called whenever the progress of the upload changes.
public event Action<IUploadProgress> ProgressChanged;

public void insertFile(String filePath)
{
    //.. some code
    insertRequest.ProgressChanged += Upload_ProgressChanged;
}

public void Upload_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
{          
     //.. I need filePath from insertFile() here!
}
```

How to pass additional paramtres to `Upload_ProgressChanged` ?

I did the following:

```
public void insertFile(String filePath)
{
    //.. some code
    ProgressChangedEventArgs args = new ProgressChangedEventArgs()
    {
        path = filePath
    };

    insertRequest.ProgressChanged += Upload_ProgressChanged;
}

static void Upload_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{

}

public class ProgressChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string path { get; set; }
}
```

And I have mistake `Can not implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Action<Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress>'`

Comment: I'd follow event pattern here...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti He already is...

Comment: I'd use _standard_ event pattern: you declared `ProgressChangedEventArgs`? Good, now let's change event from `Action<IUploadProgress>` to `EventHandler<ProgressChangedEventArgs>`. BTW do not (re)register event handler each time. Basically what barrick said in his answer (IMO it's more correct even if it implies some refactoring) adding anything you need in the `EventArgs` class. Capturing a variable is also viable (absolutely if you don't need to expose that event outside the class and you don't want to split-up code in different classes) but you have to understand it implications.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Sure it had.  The whole question from the start was how to allow an event handler to have access to a variable that was in scope when attaching the event handler, which is exactly why your last comment is entirely inappropriate, as that variable is not in scope when defining the event, and you're suggesting removing the information that *is* being exposed when firing the event.

Comment: @Servy "I did the following:" part was missing anyway: assuming `ProgressChanged` is inside another object and `fileName` must be passed to one of its methods to...actually perform upload then yes I'd change `Action<>` with `EventHandler<>` and add relevant information there. No captures and for sure I wouldn't add a new event handler for each call to `insertFile()`.

Comment: I'm suggesting to wrap uploader class in something more _.NETish_, Google API is like that but it may make some people pretty disoriented (`Action` instead of `EventHandler` to handle the event and `IUploadProgress` as parameter instead of a class derived from `EventArgs`. There I'd put extra informations (provided by uploader itself). I mean: wrap everything inside a class and hide such stuff there.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti That's removing the information that is available, and is needed, by taking away the `IUploadProgress` parameter, and also not dealing with the fact that **the code firing the event doesn't have a file path to use when invoking**.  He couldn't do that even if he wanted to.  Changing the signature of the event doesn't just make the actual information for that parameter just appear where its needed.  Additionally there is no reason at all to use `EventHandler` over `Action`.  Wasting the time to wrap the parameters in another object adds nothing productive at all.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti So you like wasting time and effort for the sake of wasting time and effort?

Comment: @Servy basically **yes**, I'd wrap `Uploader` in another class. I'd put there my `UploadFile` method and I'd expose a `Progress` event as `EventHandler<ProgressEventArgs>`. Wasting time for sake of wasting time? Well maybe but consistency (with most of .NET code out there) may save time to someone else after me.

Comment: @Adrian Repetti, but I can not change `public event Action<IDownloadProgress> ProgressChanged;` to `EventHandler<>`, because definition of the ProgressChanged in a .dll assembly.

Comment: @user3715778 yes, what I'm suggesting is to _wrap_ all that code (including your `insertFile()` method inside another class and to implement a more _common_ (or _.NETish_) interface for that. Using that class you'll call `uploader.InsertFile(path)` and you'll have a `SourcePath` property in your `UploadProgressEventArgs` argument for your `EventHandler<UploadProgressEventArgs>` `Progress` event. Of course if you care about what I said in previous comments, if you feel comfortable with such code (and your colleagues too) then as Servy said you don't need to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using an event you can capture the variable inside a closure

```
insertRequest.ProgressChanges += progress => { /* Do something with filePath here */ };
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But I do not really understand why.

Comment: What is the alternative way to do it with Events ?

Comment: @user3715778 This is the correct solution to the problem, and it is using events to solve it.

Comment: I like this explanation: https://medium.com/swlh/the-magic-of-c-closures-9c6e3fff6ff9

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, define the EventArgs class - this will let you have whatever information you like...

```
public class ProgressChgEventArgs : System.EventArgs
{
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public int InstanceId { get;set; }

    public ProgressChgEventArgs(string name, int id)
    {
        Name = name;
        InstanceId = id;
    }
}
```

Next, create the event that consumes these arguments:

```
public event EventHandler<ProgressChgEventArgs> ProgressChanged;
```

Then, have an 'On....' method that invokes the handlers

```
public void OnProgressChanged(ProgressChgEventArgs e)
{
    var handler = new EventHandler<ProgressChgEventArgs>();
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, e);
}
```

Now, at the relevant point in your code (presumably when the progress changes!) you call OnProgressChanged(), passing in an appropriate instance of the ProgressChgEventArgs:

```
private void Progress(string caller, int callerId)
{
    var arguments = new ProgressChgEventArgs(caller, callerId);
    OnProgressChanged(arguments);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, can you explain more detail ? I will glad if you help me.

Comment: The variable needed in the handler is one that is currently in scope when adding the event handler, not when firing the event, so this is entirely the wrong line of thought.

Comment: The OP is not asking for a replacement method using eventargs.